# PHP include file to all directory files by default

Tags: nginx, php7

I have a `config.php` file which I want to include to all php files in the directory.

Is there a way to include a file by default (hence I won't need to write require 'config.php' in all files)?

Nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO Q&A seems to answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14884439/5088142)

> You want to use [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). Set this directive in your
>   php.ini or .htaccess file to the path to your `config.php` file and
>   any PHP file accessed will automatically have the contents of the
>   config file prepended to it.
>
> For `.htaccess`:
>
> ```
> php_value auto_prepend_file /full/path/to/file/config.php
> ```
>
> Keep in mind this ONLY will work on a server where PHP is run as an
>   Apache module. If PHP is run as a CGI you need to add edit it in your
>   `php.ini` file or put it inside a `.user.ini` file just without the
>   `php_value` part.
>
> In `Nginx` you could add this line to server configuration inside
>   `location ~ \.php$`
>
> ```
> fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/full/path/to/file/config.php";
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I use nginx. What should I do in case when I want to add only to specific directory files? For Apache I would use .htaccess in those directories.